# R repeat n times

Tags: r

I have an application that requires sorting n objects into x sequential numbered groups. This is straightforward when the `n` objects can be divided equally among the x groups using the `rep()` function:

```
objects <- c(1: 10)
groups <- 5
assign1 <- rep(1:groups, times= (length(objects)/groups))
assign1
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

However, when objects are not evenly divisible by group size, group assignment can be either too long or too short:

```
groups <- 7
assign2 <- rep(1:groups, times= (length(objects)/groups))
assign2
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This can be remedied by:

```
assign_set <- rep(1:groups, times= (length(objects)/groups)+1 )
assign3 <- assign_set[1:length(objects)]
assign3
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```

This solution seems inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is this `rep_len` that might be what you are looking for

```
rep_len(1:7, length.out = length(objects))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```